# How to find deeply embedded children with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a dom tree that looks like this:

```
<div class="specs> 
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a></a>
    </li>
</div>
```

How would I use jquery to go through each anchor tag and add a target="_blank";

Adding classes is not an option. I'm using node with an api call off to a cms to pull in markdown and parse it into html.

What I have:

```
$('#specs-container.specs > ul > li').children('a').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want any anchor tag in `#specs-container.specs` or only those within lists?

Comment: You're using an ID in your selector, but the element has no ID. Also, there's a missing quote after the class name in the HTML, and you're missing a `</ul>`. ...so after those changes, your code works. https://jsfiddle.net/z5qqjcLx/

Comment: Only in these lists

Comment: Is there a reason you're going `> ul > li > a` rather than just `a`?

Comment: Based on the html code you presented, it should be `$('.specs > ul > li').children('a').each(function () {`

Comment: Also, `.specs` isn't needed... considering only one element on the page is identified by that id.

Comment: You don't need `.each()`. When you call `.attr()` on a collection, it does it to all items in the collection.

Comment: And you don't need to call `.children()`, just add `> a` to the selector.

Comment: You should really just read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/hierarchy-selectors/) Realize that there is a [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) which would get all of the `a`s under a specific element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
$('.specs ul li a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

But don't forget to fix your HTML code (quotes and missing closing `</ul>` tag).

HTML should be like this:

```
<div class="specs"> 
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There were a few issues with your code. Firstly, you were missing a closing `"` for your `specs` element in the HTML, next you were missing a closing `</ul>` at the end of your list, and finally your jQuery code was targeting an ID which does not exist in the HTML you provided.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.specs > ul > li').children('a').each(function () {
      $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="specs"> 
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>Test</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Test 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: See the comments from @Barmar

Comment: This was not me, but probably because of the `each` :)

Comment: That, and `$('.specs > ul > li').children('a')` can just be written `$('.specs > ul > li > a')`

Comment: The comments from @Barmar do not pertain to my answer. The OP didn't ask how else they could write the function, they asked what was wrong with their specific code, which is what this answer addresses.

Comment: @jmoerdyk a lot of things can be written in different ways, not a valid reason for a downvote.

Comment: That's your opinion... mine is that you shouldn't perpetuate inefficient code when possible.